# Good programming practice: use internal procedures to take advantage of variables scope

Tags: scope, fortran, subroutine

I am doing some coding in Fortran 95. I would like to know if using subroutines changing global variables defined in modules is considered bad programming practice. I tend to use only pure subroutines in general but in this case I cannot use "pure", right. As an alternative I could define variables in a subroutine and then use those variables in procedures internal to that subroutine, as in the example below. Is that acceptable?

```
 subroutine test(X, Y)  

  implicit none  

  integer, parameter(dp) :: kind(0.d0)
  integer, parameter(dp) :: r1d3 = 1._dp / 3._dp
  real(dp), intent(in) :: X(20)  
  real(dp), intent(out) :: Y(20)   

  real(dp) :: f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10  
  real(dp), dimension(20) :: g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, DX  

  real(dp) :: res(20), jac(20,20)  

  f1 = exp(- norm2(X(7:12)))
  g1 = X(1:6) - r1d3 * sum(X(1:3))

  ! code to calculate variables f1..., g1...   
  ! functions of X   

  ! f1 ... f10, g1 .. g7, are needed to compute both the residual and the jacobian

  call residual(X, res)  

  condition = ( norm2(res) < tol )

  ! I do not want to calculate the jacobian if this is not needed. Should I?

  if (condition) then  
    call jacobian(X, jac)  

  end if  

  DX = -res  

  call gesv(jac, DX)   

  ! and so on

contains

   pure subroutine residual(X, res)
    ....
   end subroutine residual


   pure subroutine jacobian(X, jac)
    ....
   end subroutine jacobian
```

Is the code above decently written? I could have included the computation of both the residual and the jacobian in the same subroutine and do all the needed calculations of f1 ... g7 there, avoiding the definition of residual and jacobian as internal subroutines, but I only want to calculate the jacobian if needed. What do you think?

I thought the following alternative could also work:

```
module EP_integration

   implicit none


   integer, parameter(dp) :: kind(0.d0)  
   real(dp), PRIVATE, SAVE :: f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10  
   real(dp), dimension(20), PRIVATE, SAVE :: g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7  

contains

   pure subroutine calc_funcs(X, res)
     ! calculates f1 .. f10, g1 .. g10 as functions of X
     ! f1 ... f10, g1 .. g7, are needed to compute both the residual and the jacobian
    ....
   end subroutine calc_funcs

   pure subroutine residual(X, res)
    ....
   end subroutine residual

   pure subroutine jacobian(X, jac)
    ....
   end subroutine jacobian

end module EP_integration
```

or maybe `USE`ing the module in the main subroutine instead of using the attribute `SAVE`.

Comment: If you want people to see your question, use tag [tag:fortran], just check the number of subscribers of the tags. The version tag fortran 95 use only in addition when it is necessary to specify just this 20 years old version and not more recent modern versions.

Comment: It would be much better to show some actual source code. Your question is really too broad.

Comment: I warn against changing the question that much. I know it was suggested in the comment, but you already have upvoted answer to your last question. Be sure your new question does not invalidate them (I didn't check).

Comment: sorry @VladimirF and thanks for your warning. I have started using stackoverflow recently and I am not very used to that. I added a few lines at the top of the question to make it more consistent with the previous version. I hope I did not make things worse. In case I did, could you suggest me what to do (e.g. deleting the question entirely?)

Comment: @user2078621 Oops, now I took the time to read the question fully. You really changed too much I am afraid. If I was to answer now, I would have to write an answer that the code you show is write alright. But I can't see any connection with global variables there.

Comment: Please really consider whether you need to change your question that much when you already have answer. This is not a discussion forum for continuous discussion, but a question/answer site. Of course, editing is encouraged to provide details and information requested in the comments, but it has its limits. BTW your module introduces global variables as well. Module variables ARE global variables (more or less). It is just one of many possible designs. Would it work? Yes. It is the best design? It depends and it is subjective.

Answer (score 3):

*I would like to know if using subroutines changing global variables defined in modules is considered bad programming practice.*

It certainly is widely considered to be bad practice, but I bet you know that.  As always, there are arguments for special cases.  Personally, for example, I have no problem with a value for `pi` being global, but then that's something that my programs rarely update.

The rest of your question prompts the thought that you have probably not packaged your data properly -- very long argument lists suggest to me that you may not have defined data types to organise your data at the right levels.

But beyond those broad platitudes it's very difficult to provide any kind of a good answer with so little detail in your question.

Comment: You're right, it's kind of a very general question. At some point in my code I have to do a Newton-Raphson loop, so I have subroutines computing the residual, the jacobian and updating the values of the unknowns. The point is that the residual and the jacobian are need the calculation of many functions which exist solely for this purpose.

Comment: Is there a good reason to not make something like `pi` a `parameter`?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are not a problem in themselves. The problem is the *mutability* of the variables, which is even worse when the variables are global.

What adds complexity to a code is the time dependence of the variables. This is well explained in the lecture of [Pecquet](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/polycopies/pecquet/poly.ps.gz) (if you can read french, this course explains things very well) In this code :

```
a=b
! some code
a=c
```

the variable `a` has a value that changes during the execution of the program. This change is made by changing the state of the memory using a side effect and often, this can be avoided. For example, pure functional programming languages kill this complexity by forbidding mutable variables and programs are much more under control than with imperative languages.
If `a` can be modified in another subroutine, it will be much more difficult to know in which state `a` is. And if you are in a multithreaded program where each thread can modify `a`, it can become a nightmare.

However, most scientific program make use of some entities that have to be used by the majority of the subroutines and functions, and this often leads to your question. Often, you will have to use mutable global variables in your codes, so you will have to keep them coherent. In the case of a conjugate gradient, the global variables are *mutable* between the iterations, but they are *constant* in a given iteration. Global constants (such as pi) are not a problem, since they are not time dependent. So you have two different time scales : the time scale of the CPU instructions and the time scale of the iterations. To keep the control of your code, you will have to mutate your global data at a well defined "checkpoints" (the end of each iteration), so you *know* that the global data is constant during an iteration.

A simple solution to keep the coherence is to have a global variable for the current iteration `A_current` and a variable you are constructing for the next iteration `A_next`. At the end of the iteration, you copy (or swap pointers of) the `A_next` and `A_current`. This guarantees that for a given iteration you know the global state.

For more complicated problems, you can use the Implicit Reference to Parameters (IRP) strategy explained in this [GitBook](https://www.gitbook.com/book/scemama/irpf90/details)
and you can use [IRPF90](https://github.com/scemama/irpf90) which is an open-source Fortran code generator I develop and use for all my codes to program using this method.

Answer (score 0):

In general having a lot of global variables make a code unreadable and difficult to maintain. So having several dozens (or hundred!) of global variables may be considered as the symptom of bad software design.

[Fortran95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fortran_95) has [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features) with the `TYPE` keyword. So you can define composite (and nested) [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) (made of "smaller" or "simpler" components) and use them (perhaps as [abstract data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)). You could have some functions to build composite data, and other functions to operate on them (and change them).

A rule of thumb code discipline is, for fixed arity functions (non variadic), to have them accept less than 5 to 8 formal arguments (for readability reasons, and [cognitive limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) of humans). *You are coding* not only for the computer, but also *for human colleagues* (present or future ones, perhaps even *yourself in a couple of months*) who would need to understand your source code.

Some old Fortran77 code had functions with several dozens of formal arguments, but that makes them unreadable.

If your management permits it, I strongly suggest to use at least a more recent version of Fortran, e.g. [Fortran2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Fortran_2008) (and some numerical codes are coded today in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), perhaps with some [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), for very good reasons; I even know some numerical scientists coding some code in Ocaml... So switching to some better language might be considered).

BTW, if you have no formal education in programming, I believe that learning some basics is worthwhile, even for numerical scientists. Reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (and playing with some Scheme implementation) will widen a *lot* your thinking and will improve your daily Fortran coding. Also, if you don't know it, read http://floating-point-gui.de/ which is relevant for every numerical scientist writing numerical code. It takes [ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) to learn programming (or something else, like numerical analysis), so be patient and persevering.

You could also consider using tools like [Scilab](http://scilab.org/), [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [R](https://www.r-project.org/about.html) ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, I'll certainly study more basics, although, as I said, programming is only a tiny part of my job.
About my specific problem: what if I hide this whole part of the program in a module, declaring most variables as private? In this way I can calculate the functions in subroutines of the module and wrap it in a subroutine which only returns "packed" data to the program. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Probably yes it does make sense, but I don't understand exactly what you mean. You should show some source code in your edited question

Comment: What exactly means "better language"? And OpenCL is almost dead, everyone uses CUDA, some other techniques for Xeon Phi.

Comment: CUDA is Nvidia specific. OpenCL claims to be a multivendor standard.